# Something really weird happend when dropping all tables in web2py

Tags: python, database, list, web2py

I want to drop all tables in database `db`. All I do is iterate through `db.tables` and
drop them one by one. However, some tables are ignored and therefore not dropped. Then I
changed `drop` to `truncate`, every table is truncated. So, what's wrong with `drop`?

Here are the codes:

controllers/admin.py:

```
def olddo_remove():
    response.view = 'admin/do_remove.html'
    l = []
    k = []
    for table_name in db.tables:
        l.append(table_name)
        db[table_name].drop()
        #db[table_name].truncate()
    return locals()

def do_remove():
    l = []
    k = []
    for table_name in db.tables:
        l.append(table_name)
    for table_name in l:
        k.append(table_name)
        db[table_name].drop()
    return locals()
```

views/admin/do_remove.html:

```
{{=l}}<br />{{=k}}
```

When I visit admin/olddo_remove, I get

```
['auth_user', 'auth_membership', 'auth_event', 'client', 'data']
[]
```

When I visit admin/do_remove, I get

```
['auth_user', 'auth_group', 'auth_membership', 'auth_permission', 'auth_event', 'auth_cas', 'client', 'product', 'data']
['auth_user', 'auth_group', 'auth_membership', 'auth_permission', 'auth_event', 'auth_cas', 'client', 'product', 'data']
```

If I change the `drop` to `truncate` in olddo_remove, the output will be

```
['auth_user', 'auth_group', 'auth_membership', 'auth_permission', 'auth_event', 'auth_cas', 'client', 'product', 'data']
[]
```

Why? What's wrong?

---

This is going **CRAZY**!!

```
def test():
    response.view = 'admin/do_remove.html'
    l = db.tables
    k = []
    for table_name in l:
        k.append(table_name)
        db[table_name].drop()
    return locals()
```

Output:

```
['auth_group', 'auth_permission', 'auth_cas', 'product']
['auth_user', 'auth_membership', 'auth_event', 'client', 'data']
```

And only tables on the second line were dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python issue. `db.tables` is a list object (actually, it's a special SQLCallableList object, which inherits from list). `db[table_name].drop()` not only drops the table_name table from the database but also removes table_name from the `db.tables` list. So, in the for loop, you are iterating over a list and mutating that list (i.e., deleting items from it) as you iterate. This is why you're only getting every other table. In the example that works, you are first copying the list and then iterating over the copy (which is not getting mutated in the loop), so it works as expected. Truncation works even when iterating over `db.tables` directly because truncation doesn't remove the tables (from the database or from `db.tables`).

Note, as mentioned above, `db.tables` is a SQLCallableList. That means that `db.tables()` returns a copy of the `db.tables` list, so you can instead iterate over the copy:

```
for table_name in db.tables():
    db[table_name].drop()
```

The .drop() will remove the table_name from `db.tables` but will not remove it from the `db.tables()` copy over which the for loop is iterating, so everything should work as expected.

Comment: Why would that be a bug? web2py is doing a sensible thing -- when you delete a table from the database, it removes it from db.tables as well. In Python, if you loop over a list and then mutate that list within the loop, you get this behavior. That's how Python works, and I think it is also sensible. I don't see a bug here. You just have to know how Python works.

Comment: Note, I updated the answer providing an alternative using `db.tables()`.